# Why my Console.WriteLine(); does not work on referenced external project?

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error on Console.WriteLine();
HelperLibrary Project I already reference it to my main project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MathClasses
{
    public class MyMaths
    {
      public  void Divisibility(int number, int divby)
        {

            int divisibility = number % divby;
            if (divisibility == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{number} is divisible by {divby}");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{number} is not divisible by {divby}");
            }

        }
  }
}
```

and here is my main project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MathClasses;
using MiscClasses;
using PrinterClasses;

namespace ChallengeOne
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyMaths myMaths = new MyMaths();
            
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int divby = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            myMaths.Divisibility(number, divby);
        }

        
    }
}
```

Note:

[image: different projects but one solution]

my instructor says that my 2nd project doesn't recognize my `using System;`
the error says

> The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Well, why is `HelperLibrary` a Portable project in the first place? Not only it's incorrect for this usecase, it's also obsolete

Comment: how can i make it not Portable?

Comment: @DireVader You can use a .Net Standard library, which would be a better replacement for portable libraries.

Comment: I don't remember if there's an easy way. I think you'll need to delete the project and create a new one (and make completely sure you don't select a Portable template)

Comment: ill try it brother

Comment: it doesnt work bro now i cant reference it to main project

Comment: i set it to universal windows

Comment: im trying .net library